# Is mat-icon need an alt text attribute?

Tags: angular, angular-material, accessibility

I am adding an alt text to all of my images, but I am not sure regarding mat-icon, is there a need to add an alt text to it too?

Comment: `The required alt attribute specifies an alternate text for an image, if the image cannot be displayed.`, so is recommended to add it

Comment: Not clear to me! Can you please explain?

Comment: So add it to my mat icon although I have an aria label on the button? or just add an empty alt?

Comment: I now see the my html tag was deleted, I edited the question. I need to now if U need to add alt attribute to mat-icon.

Comment: Post a code sample.  Alt text is for <img> elements.  Other elements that need alternative text are usually done with the `aria-label` attribute, but it's hard to make an exact recommendation without seeing your code example.

Answer (score 1):

It depends - if the icon is being displayed instead of text for a button, then it is considered better to use an appropriate `aria-label` on the button element.

For icons that are indications of something, but not directly interactive then you may want to add a sibling element, eg: `span` that contains a textual representation of the indicator, and mark this element using the class `cdk-visually-hidden`.

**Quote From the official docs:**

> Similar to an  element, an icon alone does not convey any useful information for a screen-reader user. The user of  must provide additional information pertaining to how the icon is used. Based on the use-cases described below, mat-icon is marked as aria-hidden="true" by default, but this can be overriden by adding aria-hidden="false" to the element.
>
> In thinking about accessibility, it is useful to place icon use into one of three categories:
>
> Decorative: the icon conveys no real semantic meaning and is purely cosmetic.
>
> Interactive: a user will click or otherwise interact with the icon to perform some action.
>
> Indicator: the icon is not interactive, but it conveys some information, such as a status. This includes using the icon in place of text inside of a larger message.

ref: https://material.angular.io/components/icon/overview#accessibility

Answer (score 0):

Other option is use matTooltip:

```
                    <!--edit Column -->
                    <ng-container matColumnDef="edit">
                        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> </th>
                        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
                            <button mat-icon-button color="accent" matTooltip="Editar pesquisa" (click)="editSurvey(element)">
                                <mat-icon>edit</mat-icon>
                            </button>
                        </td>
                    </ng-container>
```